# IntelliJ Suppress Deprecated Warning For Certain Method?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

is there any option to suppress deprecated warnings only for certain methods?

Thanks

Comment: 1) No there isn't.  2) This is what `@SuppressWarnings` is for.

Answer (score 4):

Put this annotation on your method:

```
@SuppressWarnings( "deprecation" )
```

To suppress all warnings you can do

```
@SuppressWarnings("all")
```

but this is not suggested because these warning alaways exist for a reason...

Comment: Yes, I know. But is there any option from IntelliJ to just suppress all warnings for one certain method, without annotation?

Comment: OK i edited my answer but plz be more specificnext time...

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate the methods with the `@SuppressWarnings("deprecated")` annotation.
read more about that here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html